# Highrise CRM contact search API

Tags: highrise

I'm trying to get a contact in Highrise CRM using the following API:

/people/search.xml?email=emailID

But the results are not related to the email of the contact I asked for.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the API docs here:
https://github.com/basecamp/highrise-api/blob/master/sections/people.md#search-people

Looks like your query string doesn't match the criteria format.

Also, try running curl to see what the response is and post it, might help to clarify. :)

Answer (score 0):

API that works:

/people/search.xml?criteria[email]=emailID